# Flutter Authentication Bloc not updating the main page after success state change

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

First of all here the the code inside main.dart which handle which screen to initiate depending upon the user authentication status.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Smart City',
      theme: appTheme,
      routes: routes,
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
        switch (state.status) {
          case AuthenticationStatus.loading:
            return const Splash();
          case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:
            return const Home();
          case AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated:
            return const IntroScreen();
        }
      }),

    );
  }
```

Above code works fine after starting the application.
Now the `Introscreen()` contains multiple screens as a signup process.

So after successfull signup i usually fire the event `LoggedIn()`  from the `BlocListener`.Like this.

`context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(LoggedIn());` this does update the state but it doesn't change the screen to `Home()` after the `AuthenticationStatus` is `authenticated`.

So i have to write code like this.
`context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(LoggedIn());`
`Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);`

Using

`Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);`

line solves the issue and after successful signup now it's redirected to home.

Can anyone help regarding this?
Why screen doesn't change after the states changes and the code inside `switch-case` executes too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: need bloc file code

Comment: void _onLoggedIn(LoggedIn event, Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
  String userId = await SharedPreferencesHelper.instance.getStringValue('id');
  String name = await SharedPreferencesHelper.instance.getStringValue('name');

  User user = User(
    name: name,
    id: userId,
  );
  emit(AuthenticationState.authenticated(user));
}

Somethings like this for LoggedIn Event

Comment: in 7.3 bloc little different, you read this https://bloclibrary.dev/#/ ? for example login https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial

Comment: Yes ! Taken refrence only